# Problem after TeX Live update

Tags: graphics, xetex, pstricks, updating

**Code**

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
  \rput(5,5){\includegraphics[height = 0.1\textheight]{smiley.jpg}}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

I am compiling using `xelatex`.

**Output**

[image: acreenshot]

**Question**

Why is the picture (smiley) not centered inside the `\fbox` but instead placed at `(0,0)` and how to I fix this?

When compiling the document a few days ago, it was all fine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just tried this with example-image and a texlive 2020 updated today and the image was centred in the box?

Comment: I get your output at learnlatex.org  (up to date linux texlive) but I can't reproduce with this cygwin build

Comment: Ulrike sees the bad output in a windows texlive as well so it isn't you....

Comment: if you replace the image by `X` is it still mis placed?

Comment: Yes. It is still placed at `(0,0)` if I replace the image by an `X`.

Comment: then everything is OK, the example can be re-done without graphicx and **It's not my fault** as I'm sure you will agree:-)

Comment: Why is everything okay? `:-)` If I use `\rput(5,5){X}` it is placed at `(0,0)` and not at `(5,5)`.

Comment: no clearly something is broken I just meant that it isn't broken in a package with my name on it so it's OK for me. But I can not reproduce here so hard for me to debug, I suspect it's an xdvipdfmx driver issue but I have no idea yet.

Comment: I see! Yes, it is definitely not your fault. `:-)` Please let me know if you figure out how to fix the issue. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I just ran \tracingall here and at a site that shows the problem and got identical logs so it looks like it is in xdvipdfmx or ghostscript  (I have gs 9.52 here) have you updated that recently?

Comment: Output from terminal: `[<username>@localhost ~]$ ghostscript

GPL Ghostscript 9.53.1 (2020-09-14)`

Comment: @egreg what versions of gs and xdvipdfmx do you have (I have gs 9.52 and its OK Ulrike and Svend have 9.53.x and it isn't but I don't know if that is actually the cause)

Comment: I have GLP gs 9.26 and the example seems fine (on an up to date TL20 upstream)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's a Ghostscript thing. Definitely. I updated from GS 9.50 to 9.53 and the problem shows.

Comment: I just installed Ghostscript 9.52 and now everything is fine. Thank you for your help, everyone!

Comment: Fixed in the TeXLive svn sources for dvipdfm-x. Many thanks for the report.